# How to change tags h2 to other tags header in jquery

Tags: jquery

what is the function change tag h2 to other tag header(tag HTML) in jquery ? if not exist this function then i can use the syntax. how? thanks everyone !
ex:

```
<h2>DEMO</h2> ---> <h3>DEMO</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replaceWith()` selector:

```
$('h2').replaceWith(function () {
  return $('<h3/>', {html: this.innerHTML});
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p5gd27t0/)**

Answer (score 1):

use **[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** in jquery

```
$("h2").replaceWith(function(i,cont){
return "<h3>"+cont+"</h3>";      // cont will return the inner html
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h2vafcdz/)